# Liferay DDLRecord date format

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to add a record in my DDL by DDLRecordLocalServiceUtil.addRecord() but I can't find which format to give into the fields map, it always add the record with "1/1/70".

I'm doing like this:

```
Map<String,Serializable> test = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
    test.put("date-value", "21/04/1983");
    test.put("number-value", 15);[/code]
```

I tried with "04/21/1983" and with - instead of / but it always ignore my date...

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try it with the time in milliseconds: `test.put("date-value", myDate.getTime())`? If I read the implementation correctly, this could work. Otherwise you could try the method with an explicit `Fields` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're passing a Serializable object who's value is a String Liferay doesn't know that `"04/21/1983"` is a `Date` and will insert it as a String. I think you should pass a `Date` object and use SimpleDateFormater to convert your string to a date:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
test.put(dateFormatter.parse("21/04/1983"));
```

SOLUTION FOUND : SEE IN COMMENTS

Comment: You mean `dd/mm/yyyy` and `test.put("date-value", ...)`? But I'd guess that this won't work neither, as `DDLRecordLocalServiceImpl.toFields(long, Map<String, Serializable>)` converts always to a string, no matter what you add: `String value = String.valueOf(fieldsMap.get(name));`

Comment: Ah, sorry, must have been a bad day.And as for the second part you may be also right, setting the timestamp may be the soulution

Comment: **Solution found thanks to @tobias-liefke**

Use a Calendar object, set it with the date you want then pass to "date-value" (in my example) the YourCalendarDate.getTimeInMillis().